# Trouble using ProPac in Mathematica 11

Tags: packages, commercial-package

Has anyone tried using ProPac package [here](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~hgk22/software/ProPac/ProPac.html) on Mathematica 11? It seams to not work anymore.

Comment: Have you also tried e-mailing the authors about this?

Comment: @J.M. No, I might do that.

Comment: were you able to install ProPac? Thank you, B

Comment: Nope. Let me know if you manage to do that!